# How can I delete something from the Apple Pay wallet

Tags: iphone, wallet

How do I remove an old boarding pass for Amtrak?  Tried settings, tried the info button on the lower right corner, I just don’t see any option to delete.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you are using the Wallet app while your device is unlocked. You cannot make any changes to passes, cards, etc, when you are accessing the Wallet with the home-button double-click *when the device is locked.*

Answer (score 4):

There should be a **Remove** option when tapping the info icon.

[image: info icon]

In the information one will see the **Remove Pass** option (May have to scroll):

[image: remove pass]